# React map undefined error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on react social network app. Here when I add one post, then both the edit post and comment post work perfectly well. but from the subsequent post both the edit and comment functionalities are not working.

below is the error when I am trying to add comment in the 2nd post:

react-dom.production.min.js:188 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

```
src/components/PostList.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostListItem from './PostListItem';

const PostList = (props) =>(
<div>
  <h1>Posts List</h1>
  {props.posts && props.posts.map((post) =>{
      console.log(post);
      return(
        <PostListItem 
        key={post.id}
        {...post}
        />
      );
  })
}
</div>
```

);

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log(state);
return{
    posts: state.posts
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostList)
```

this [is the github link of the app](https://github.com/sujoys10/Goal)

Comment: can you please include the relevant code directly in your question? Makes it easier for people who want to answer as opposed to following the link you provided.

Comment: Updated the post with Postlist Component.

Comment: may be one of the post inside your posts array is undefined.

Comment: I am adding post through browser and the post is also shown in the dashboard page.but  When I am trying to add comment to the 2nd or subsequent post, I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sujoys10/Goal/blob/eeb4ee1b74f139c6f7061e24dd9607045187b49a/src/reducers/post.js#L40 
`return post;` is missing after line 40

Comment: I had missed else blocks in reducer. So when the if condition was not matching , i was getting the undefined error